# Javascript - Bit Alarm Messages - get all possible combinations

Tags: javascript

i had the problem that i had an alarm message which is in a byte

example:
1) 0000 0001 - is alarm 1
2) 0000 0010 - is alarm 2
3) 0000 1000 - is alarm 3
4) 1000 0000 - is alarm 4

so the problem is that if alarm 1 and alarm 4 is at the same time the byte looks like this: 1000 0001 and if it is alarm 1, 2 and 4 its: 1000 0011
is it possible to get all possible combinations for the alarm with a javascript function?

i know there are only 4 but this is only a example i had some with all 8 bits

thank you in advance

Comment: Why have you created your own byte system? Isn't a 3-bit binary number a ready-to-go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work to get all bits with 'normal' bit comparison:

```
var val = 0b00000101;

function GetBits(val){
    var i = 1, res = [];
    while(i<=val){
        if(i & val) res.push(i);
        i <<=1;
    }
    return res;
}

console.log(GetBits(val));
```

But it looks like an alternate bit mask is used?

If the alarms are objects with a custom mask each, in an array, you can use `filter`:

```
var alarms = [
    {descr: 'Alarm 1', mask  : 1},
    {descr: 'Alarm 2', mask  : 2},
    {descr: 'Alarm 3', mask  : 0b1000},
    {descr: 'Alarm 4', mask  : 0b10000000}
    ];

var val = 0b10000011;

var alarmsInVal = alarms.filter(function(a){ return val & a.mask;});

console.log(alarmsInVal);
```

And an example of getting a string of the above filtered values:

```
var descr =  alarmsInVal.map(function(a){return a.descr;}).join(', '); //Alarm 1, Alarm 2, Alarm 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to find all combinations to determine if the alarm is on. Use the bitwise AND operator.

```
var isAlarm1On = (alarm & 1) === 1;
var isAlarm2On = (alarm & 2) === 2;
var isAlarm3On = (alarm & 8) === 8;
var isAlarm4On = (alarm & 128) === 128;
```

This will be true for any byte where the least significant bit is a 1.

The following will be true:
0000 0001

0000 0011

1000 0001

1111 0001

1111 1111

Comment: Here is some documentation on the bitwise operators: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: sounds good but i need all combinations as a string for dokumentation is there also a way?

Comment: You could write a loop that iterates over every integer between 0-255, and use that code i just gave you to determine if it is true for alarm 1 and print out the binary number.

Comment: for(var i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
    if(( i & 1) === 1) {
        console.log((i >>> 0).toString(2));
    }
}